# Understanding summary of inner query

Tags: sql, sqlite

**Problem understanding subquery**

I do not understand this example from www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-subquery :
[image]

Only one number is returned by the inner query: 1422138358

[image]

But the average of this number is different:

[image]

So why is the average of 1422138358 not 1422138358? The two queries are not independent? If I remove "ORDER BY albumid" the result is the same:

[image]

Example data:
http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-sample-database/

**Edit**: Ok, there is probably some integer overflow going on as the columns are integer, but I still don't understand why the example take the average of a single number?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very possibly that it was a mistake

1)
From the text you can see that they wanted to '*sum the size of an album*' and you`re querying Tracks table, which supposedly have an album_ID column

2)
You cannot use ORDER BY if you`re using only aggregation column
such as

```
select SUM(bytes)
from Tracks
Order by albumID
```

because it has nothing to order it by from.

Also note that you **cannot** **use** **order by in subqueries**

Finally what was missing here was this remaining of the query :

```
Select AVG(album.size) as [avg(album.size)]
from (
select albumID,SUM(bytes) as size
from Tracks
GROUP BY albumID

) as album
```

You can learn more about subqueries [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(v=sql.105).aspx)

And if you want to play around with these, heres the code that you can replicate and use it for further exercies on that website:

```
    CREATE TABLE tracks (AlbumID int,bytes int)
    CREATE TABLE albums (AlbumID int, title nvarchar(50))
    insert into Tracks values (1,2),(2,10),(3,15)
    Select AVG(album.size) as [avg(album.size)]
    from (
    select AlbumID,SUM(bytes) as size
    from tracks
    GROUP BY albumID

) as album
```

Hope it helps